# Finding frictional force of an object on a slope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, friction

Below is a question I'm trying to solve but I can't seem to get the same answer as what the solution is showing me. Is the solution wrong or is there a mistake in the way of how I think?

Question:

> A person pulls on a 50kg desk with a 200N force acting at 30 degrees angle above the horizon. The desk does not budge. Determine the value of the frictional force.

I first drew a free body diagram and from the diagram I have:

$$\begin{align}F_x&=W\cdot g\cdot\sin(\theta)\\&= m\cdot g\cdot\sin(\theta)\\& = 50\cdot 9.81\cdot\sin(30)\\&= 245.25\mathrm{N}\end{align}$$

But since the object is not budging that means the forces going in the $x$ direction (along the slope) must sum to 0. Therefore I think the frictional force should be:

$$\begin{align}F_f& = 245.25 - 200\\& = 45.25 \mathrm{N}\end{align}$$

But the answer sheet tells me it's $173.2\mathrm{N}$.

I really have no idea where that comes from. Your guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Is this the full question text? Did a sketch follow along?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because home-work like questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no slope. The body is on a horizontal surface. The force is at an angle from the horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misread the question. Nowhere does it say there is a slope. I think the desk is on flat ground and it's just the force that's at an angle.

A much simpler problem, and gives the answer sought (I think you will see how, you seem to know what you're doing).